# Django celery tasks in separate server

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

We have two servers, Server A and Server B. Server A is dedicated for running django web app. Due to large number of data we decided to run the celery tasks in server B. Server A and B uses a common database. Tasks are initiated after post save in models from Server A,webapp. How to implement this idea using rabbitmq in my django project

Comment: That is exactly how Celery is supposed to work, and there is nothing unusual here. Where are you having problems?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have 2 servers, 1 project and 2 settings(1 per server).

server A (web server + `rabbit`)

server B (only `celery` for workers)

Then you set up the broker url in both settings. Something like this:

`BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:password@IP_SERVER_A:5672//'` matching server A to IP of server A in server B settings.

For now, any task must be sent to `rabbit` in server A to virtual server /.

In server B, you must just initialize `celery` worker, something like this:

```
python manage.py celery worker -Q queue_name -l info
```

and thats it.

**Explanation**: `django` sends messages to `rabbit` to queue a task, then `celery` workers request some message to execute a task.

**Note**: Is not required that `rabbitMQ` have to be installed in server A, you can install rabbit in server C and reference it in the `BROKER_URL` in both settings(A and B) like this: `BROKER_URL='amqp://user:password@IP_SERVER_C:5672//'`.

Sorry for my English.

greetings.

Comment: Nothing wrong in your English.  Crisp and clear information. Thanks

Comment: @Diego how would you theoretically point to a second worker D on a different machine and let RabbitMQ (assuming it's the broker) handle the load from Celery? Is it done automatically as long as you list all workers?

Comment: @tech4242 I don't understand, what do you mean with "worker D"? you want many workers by server? can you reformulate? This question does not mention about AMPQ protocol(or how rabbit does put a message on a queue).

Comment: Yes! Simply meant what happens when you want multiple workers - each one on a different server (doesn’t matter if physical or virtual) How do you tell your broker that you have multiple workers on different servers when you use Celery

Comment: @tech4242 the broker don't need to know the number of workers. The broker just have to know where put the message(in what queue). If you want more workers, instructions for server B will work for server N. In each settings you set broker url and in the start command you tell from what queue you want to process mesaages.

Comment: obviously you can add many workers by server with the same command.